# What would a planet with fifty foot tall arachnids need to make this possible?

Tags: xenobiology

I'm writing a race for my series. They are a large terrestrial arachnid-like species, with fifty feet being their minimum height. The idea is that they evolved over millions of years, leading to their descendants now being smaller, and humanoid in their aesthetic but  far stronger as a matter of their size to weight ratio than their ancestors. My question is what recipe for a world would I need on paper  to justify the ancestors being in excess of over fifty feet tall in the first place...

The species are not hard arachnid, they are as close to arachnids as I want to get without leaning too much on earth based presumptions of what they could be like. They bear scorpion like exoskeletions, robust muscle groups beyond what our spiders have (probably closer to humans/mammals) and are as a result quick even for their larger size. I want them to weigh less that 20 tonnes (if possible).

They have eight legs, some much smaller ones have "wings", webbing that acts as wings between their arms. They have two eyes that blend eight vision types and double corneas, one acting as a tint in certain lights or an offset for a visual disruption. They can emit lighting via electomagnitism through the tips of their arms and hairs on their bodies. Smaller ones can cover themselves in their "webbing",which is more like printable membrane(?) with chromatophores, allowing the web to mimick surroundings, ergo concealing them.

They are very intelligent and non conventional conquers by nature, and even though they can conquer with ocewhelming force, they instead focusing on economic enterprizing. They can convert other species through blank mutagenic DNA, injected into a non species. Because of this, they take prisoners in war, but only to create hybrids suitable for worlds too hostile for they themselves. These hybrids, often become generals, and are treated as champions, and allowed to live lavishly (think gladiators) making them stay.

I have some ideas of the world I want (vaired, rainforest world with lots of food, large deserts witn oasis, and deep sharp and cave filled canyons, a deceptive paradise) but understand If thats not possible. I'm mainly looking for world parameters; I want the world they inhabit to be both scientifically plausable and something the reader can look at and go, "it makes sense they evolved to have X,Y,Z".  so what ideal world works most to establish these traits/or species?

Comment: Can you tell a bit more about your 55ft tall spiders? Are they as close as they could be to spiders (aside from size), or are there differences (tell them if that's the case)? You should notably tell us if they have an exoskeleton or not as it's quite essential here. Exoskeletons creatures like insects are known to have huge issues to solve when they grow up in size.

Comment: Lower gravity and more food sounds like a good solution.

Comment: @Tortliena that's a good point, though I don't know how to adjust the question once asked, how do I do that? I literally just made an account so everything is new to me here 

Comment: @KayaSummerland You should have a [button at the bottom of your post, on the left to your signature](https://imgur.com/a/KhhD2DV). If you're lazy, you can also click this [link](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/posts/245671/edit) (for this post only though!)

Comment: @Kaya Summerland I have added a bit to part two and several other parts to my answer on May 3 to 4, offering several more suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Some writers don't care how implausible parts of their stories are while others care a lot.

https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/SlidingScale/MohsScaleOfScienceFictionHardness

I find it a lot easier to believe in 50 foot tall arachnids living in zero g in a space habitat than on the surface of a planet.

Is the fifty foot height the height of a specimen walking on all eight legs, or the height of a specimen rearing up vertically on one or two pairs of hind legs?

In the latter case the overall mass would be significantly lower which would help a lot.

Part One: Respiration.

Many arachnids get oxygen by diffusion through tracheae which greatly limits their possible size.  Some arachnids have book lungs, and some transport oxygen in their blood. That should enable those arachnids to grow larger.

Of course your "arachnids" are not really arachnids or any type of Earth life form, unless they are descended from Arachnid brought from Earth to that planet.  Thus they would be alien beings that resemble arachnids.  They can be different from Earth arachnids in many ways, including have more efficient breathing, enabling them to grow to larger sizes.

One way to enable arachnid like animals to grow to giant size would be to increase the oxygen in the air.  If human characters are supposed to visit that planet they might need breathing masks or full spacesuits if the atmosphere is too dense for them.  The limits of atmospheric composition for unprotected humans to survive in are discussed in *Habitable Planets for Man*, Stephen Dole, (1964).

https://www.rand.org/content/dam/rand/pubs/commercial_books/2007/RAND_CB179-1.pdf

Animals native to the planet could have evolved to survive in a much denser atmosphere than humans, but some factors would limit how dense an atmosphere they could survive in.

Part Two: Body Structure and Gravity.

Arachnids are a class of arthropods, animals with skeletons on the inside.  Their limbs are hollow tubes with their muscles on the inside.  And there are limits to how big their bodies and their limbs can get before their bodies crack under their weight and their limbs break and they are unable to move their limbs anyway.

The limits for Earth arthropods can be exceeded by making shells out of a stronger material than on Earth.  Or course there are some limits to how much stronger the shell material can be, since there are limits on what materials biological beings can produce in their bodies.  I am not an expert materials strength nor on what biological organism could possible secret.

The limits for Earth arthropods can also be exceeded by lowering the surface gravity of the planet, thus making the arachnids stronger relative to the gravity of the planet.

If the 50 foot tall arachnids have a vertical body position they can be a lot smaller and lighter than if they have a horizontal body position.

For example, the tallest giraffe recorded was almost 20 feet tall.

> Fully grown giraffes stand 4.3–5.7 m (14–19 ft) tall, with males taller than females.[46] The average weight is 1,192 kg (2,628 lb) for an adult male and 828 kg (1,825 lb) for an adult female.[47]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giraffe

If, for example, a 16 foot tall giraffe weighs 2,628 pounds, a 50 foot tall giraffe would weigh 30.5 times as much, or over 80,000 pounds.

Added May 4, 2023.

And take elephants as another example.

> The African bush elephant (Loxodonta africana), also known as the African savanna elephant, is one of two extant African elephant species and one of three extant elephant species.
>
> The African bush elephant is the largest and heaviest land animal, with a maximum recorded shoulder height of an adult bull of 3.96 m (13.0 ft), and an estimated weight of 10.4 t (11.5 short tons).[4](https://The%20African%20bush%20elephant%20is%20the%20largest%20and%20heaviest%20land%20animal,%20with%20a%20maximum%20recorded%20shoulder%20height%20of%20an%20adult%20bull%20of%203.96%20m%20(13.0%20ft),%20and%20an%20estimated%20weight%20of%2010.4%20t%20(11.5%20short%20tons).%5B3%5D)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_bush_elephant

So an elephant scaled up to 50 at the shoulders would weight about 56.8 times as much or 590 t or 653 short tons.

There is a statue of a circus elephant named Romeo in Delavan, Wisconsin.  I have read that the statue was 19 feet tall and that it was life size.  And someone else on the internet combined both and claimed that Romeo was 19 feet tall at the shoulder.  Actually Romeo was nearly 11 feet tall at the shoulder.

The statue shows Romeo rearing up on his hind legs about to trample a clown, so it is much taller than Romeo's shoulder height.

A circus elephant a century ago was trained to walk on his hind legs for long distances, hundreds of feet, while carrying a woman standing on his tusks.

And I have seen many photos of large male African elephants about 10 to 11 feet tall at the shoulders, weighing about 6 t or 6.6 short tons, standing on their hind legs and reaching up into tall tree branches with their trunks.

In that posture the bases of their trunks might be about 15 to 17 feet above the ground, so their trunks should reach over 20 feet high. An elephant large enough to reach 50 feet high would weigh aboot 15.6 times as much - 96 t or 103 short tons. About one sixth of the weight of an elephant 50 feet tall at the shoulder.

End of May 4, 2023 addition.

Thus the importance of giving 50 foot tall arachnids a vertical posture and making them as slender as possible, to decrease their weight.

> Like all arthropods, arachnids have an exoskeleton, and they also have an internal structure of cartilage-like tissue, called the endosternite, to which certain muscle groups are attached. The endosternite is even calcified in some Opiliones.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arachnid

So if your "arachnids" have a sort of an endoskeleton as well as an exoskeleton, with muscles attached to both, they will resemble Earth arachnids in that respect.

And of course your "arachnids" could have internal skeletons only, and their apparent exoskeletons could be a type of armor only, like the shells of turtles or the armor of armadillos.  People from Earth would call them arachnids because they looked like spiders.

Anyway, to get 50 foot tall animals, whether they have endoskeletons, exoskeletons, or both, a lower surface gravity on the planet would be very helpful.

Part Three: Surface gravity and Escape Velocity.

There are two results of the gravitational force of a planet important to habitability.  One is the surface gravity and one is the escape velocity.

The surface gravity of a planet causes the weight people feel at the surface, weight which can cause a large enough animal to be stuck in one place and starve to death because it is too heavy to move, weight which can cause a large enough animal's exoskeleton to snap and shatter, spilling its guts out on the ground.

The escape velocity of a planet is very important to retaining an atmosphere, an atmosphere necessary for multicellular animals to breath oxygen, and necessary for the planet to have liquid surface water.

Here are links to a surface gravity calculator and an escape velocity calculator that I sometimes use.

[https://philip-p-ide.uk/doku.php/blog/articles/software/surface_gravity_calc](https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/escape-velocity)

https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/escape-velocity

a rule of thumb is given by Dole on pages 35 to 36. The ratio between the escape velocity of the world divided by the root-mean-square velocity of a gas gives how long it will take for the original amount of that gas in the escape layer of the atmosphere to be reduced to 0.368 of the original amount.  If the time to reduce the gas by that much is long enough, the gas might be replaced from various sources as fast or faster than it is lost.

According to table 5 on page 35, if that  ratio is 1 or 2 the time to reduce the gas to 0.368 is zero, while if the ratio is 6 the time to reduce the gas that much is infinite.

According to Dole on page 54, the temperature in Earth's exosphere where gases escape from Earth is between 1000 degrees Kelvin and 2000 Kelvin. Since the surface temperature of Earth is 288 degrees Kelvin, the exosphere has about 3.472 to 6.944 times as high a temperature as the surface of the Earth.

Dole says that if a planet Could have an Earthlike surface temperature and a maximum exosphere temperature of only 1000 Kelvin it would need an escape velocity of five times 1.25 kilometers per second, the root-mean-square velocity of atomic oxygen at that temperature,  or 6.25 kilometers per second, to retain 0.368 of the original amount of oxygen for about 100 million years.  6.25 kilometers per second is about 0.558 of Earth's escape velocity of 11.186 kilometers per second.

Dole calculated that such a world would have a mass of 0.195 Earth mass, a radius of 0.63 Earth radius, and a surface gravity of 0.49 g.  Note that the surface gravity and the escape velocity do not have the same ratio to Earth's values, and thus they have to be calculated separately every time.

In this article from 2013, a paragraph on ages 3 to discusses the possible mass range for a habitable world.

https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1209/1209.5323.pdf

> A minimum mass of an exomoon is required to drive a magnetic shield on a billion-year timescale (Ms ≳ 0.1M⊕, Tachinami et al. 2011); to sustain a substantial, long-lived atmosphere (Ms ≳ 0.12M⊕, Williams et al. 1997; Kaltenegger 2000);

https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/9000072/

[Kaltenegger, L. 2000, ESA Special Publication, 462, 199](https://Kaltenegger,%20L.%202000,%20ESA%20Special%20Publication,%20462,%20199)

Assuming that a world with 0.12 the mass of Earth had a density like that of Mars, 3.995 grams per cubic centimeter, 0.7245 that of Earth, it would have a volume of 0.12 Earth volume divided by 0.7245, or 0.165631471 Earth volume.  That would give it a radius of about 0.5491794 Earth radius, or about 3,498.82 kilometers.  And that gives a surface gravity of 0.4 g and an escape velocity of 5.229 kilometers per second, 0.467 that of Earth.

So possibly a planet with an escape velocity as low as 5.229 kilometers per second could retain a dense atmosphere - possibly if it was composed of gases heavier than oxygen, like carbon dioxide.

And possibly a world with an even lower escape velocity could have a dense atmosphere.

To be continued.

Added May 3, 2023.

Part Four:  A Titanic World.

Actually it is more of a Titanian world than a titanic or giant world.

Titan, the largest moon of Saturn, has a radius of 2574.73 Kilometers (0.404 Erath's) a volume of (0.066 Earth's) and a mass of 0.0225 Earth's). It has a surface gravity of 0.138 g, which is even less than the surface gravity of the Moon, and an escape velocity of 2.641 kilometers per second (0.236
Earth's).

That is a considerably lower escape velocity than any object so far considered to be theoretically capable of retaining atmosphere for geological eras of time.

But Titan has a significant atmosphere.

> Titan is the only known moon with a significant atmosphere,[42] and its atmosphere is the only nitrogen-rich dense atmosphere in the Solar System aside from Earth's. Observations of it made in 2004 by Cassini suggest that Titan is a "super rotator", like Venus, with an atmosphere that rotates much faster than its surface.[43] Observations from the Voyager space probes have shown that Titan's atmosphere is denser than Earth's, with a surface pressure about 1.45 atm. It is also about 1.19 times as massive as Earth's overall,[44] or about 7.3 times more massive on a per surface area basis.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titan_(moon)#Atmosphere

Since Titan has a surface gravity only 0.138 of Earth's, perhaps land animals on Titan could grow to have 7.24 times the height or 7.24 times the body mass than the largest land animals on Earth.

Titan is very cold.

> Titan's surface temperature is about 94 K (−179.2 °C).

[Titan's surface temperature is about 94 K (−179.2 °C).](https://Titan%27s%20surface%20temperature%20is%20about%2094%20K%20(%E2%88%92179.2%20%C2%B0C).)

94 K is about 0.3264 of Earth's mean surface temperature of 288 K.  If the temperatures in the exosphere of Titan are 0.3264 of Earth's exosphere temperatures of 1000 to 2000 K, those exosphere temperatures would be about 326 to 653 K, and the root-mean-square velocities  of gases in Titan's exosphere would be much lower than in earth's exosphere, enabling Titan to hold onto gases for much longer than it could if it had temperatures similar to Earth's.

So unless you want your arachnids to have a totally different biochemistry than Earth life, using liquid methane in place of water, what is needed is a way to make the surface temperature of a world with the escape velocity of Titan be similar to Earth's, while the exosphere temperature is a low as Titan's or lower.

But shouldn't the exosphere temperatures and the surface temperature vary in the same amount?

The exosphere temperatures of worlds are believed to be caused by ultraviolet radiation, especially extreme ultraviolet radiation, from their stars, and not by the full spectrum of radiation from their stars.

But what good does that do, if moving a world closer or to farther from its star will increase or decrease the full spectrum and the ultraviolet in the same ratio and thus change both temperatures in the same ratio?

Even though all stars emit radiation in all the bands and frequencies of the electromagnetic spectrum, they don't emit all wavelengths in equal amounts, but emit more more of some wavelengths and less of others.  The amount of radiation of a specific frequency which a star emits depends on its temperature.

Hotter stars emit more ultra violet radiation, and cooler stars emit less ultraviolet radiation.  The Sun is a spectral class G2V star.  So all cooler G class stars, and all K class stars, and all M class stars emit less ultraviolet radiation than the Sun does, the less the cooler the star is.

So it is possible that some spectral types of main sequence stars are cool enough to emit small enough amounts of ultraviolet radiation that a world like Titan might have low enough exosphere temperatures to retain atmosphere for geological eras while have surface temperatures warm enough for liquid water using life.

However, I don't know how to do the calculations.

I also note that there are some problems with the theoretical habitability of planets or moons orbiting low mass class M stars.   See here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habitability_of_red_dwarf_systems

Part Five: A World Without a Star.

Large astronomical objects come in three general classes: Planets, stars, and objects called brown dwarfs.  the dividing line between planets and brown dwarfs is about 13 Jupiter masses, and the dividing line between brown dwarfs is about 75 Jupiter masses.  Brown dwarfs are massive enough to fuse deuterium for at least part of their lives, but not massive enough to fuse hydrogen.

Since brown dwarfs are not planets or stars, objects which orbit them should not be called moons or planets, but something else, which unfortunately astronomers have not decided on yet, so I will just call your world a world.

The brown dwarf would emit a lot of infrared radiation, which the native animals would have evolved to see with, and some visible light, and very little ultraviolet radiation.  And if there were no stars in the system with the brown dwarf, the nearest stars would be a few light years away.

So the exosphere of the planet should have a very low temperature.  Gas in the exosphere would probably turn to liquid and fall lower in the atmosphere, be heated up, and rise again.

But the surface of the world would be heated up by visible light and infrared radiation from the brown dwarf, and possibly by infrared light from any planet it might orbit.

And if the world had the right type of orbit around a giant planet, or directly around the brown dwarf, tidal interactions with the planet and/or the brown dwarf might cause considerable tidal heating of the interior of the planet, and that heat would escape to the surface of the world.

Io, a moon of Jupiter, has so much tidal heating that it is a volcanic hell with many different volcanoes erupting at the same time.  So it seems like a lesser amount of tidal heating might raise the surface temperature of a world orbiting a brown dwarf by tens or hundreds of degrees K, and in some cases make it warm enough for liquid water when it otherwise wouldn't be.

I note that Titan is largely made of water ice.  If Titan had a surface temperature warm enough for liquid water, all the ice would melt and Titan would have a world wide ocean almost 2,000 kilometers deep.

You want your world to have a lower average density than the Moon, in order to have both a lower surface gravity and a higher escape velocity.

Titan has a mean density of 1.8798 grams per cubic centimeter, 0.562 that of the Moon's 3.344 grams per cubic centimeter, because Titan is half ice and half rock.  You want your world to be almost entirely rock.

Undoubtedly a world can be designed that is all rock and with lower surface gravity and higher escape velocity than the moon.

The major part of the definition of planet is that it is a planetary mass object or planemo, an object massive enough for its gravity to pull itself into a spheroid shape.

The smallest planemo in our solar system which is mostly rock is Ceres.  And Ceres has a significant amount of ice in its crust, so if it was warm enough for liquid surface water the entire world might be covered with an ocean.

Part Six: A Shellworld.

If Ceres could be made habitable it would certainly have a low enough surface gravity, 0.029 that of Earth's, and land animals might get to be 34.48 times as tall, or 34.48 times as massive, as on Earth. But it has an escape velocity of only 0.516 kilometers per second.

And I don't know know if it would be possible for a world with such a low escape velocity to retain an atmosphere even at zero degrees Kelvin in the exosphere.

Shellworlds are several hypothetical types of megastructures.  One type of shellworld is:

> An inflated canopy holding high pressure air around an otherwise airless world to create a breathable atmosphere.[7](https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/escape-velocity) The pressure of the contained air supports the weight of the shell.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellworld

So in a massive terraforming effort by an advanced civilization a canopy, roof, or shell could be built around Ceres and held up by the pressure of the artificial atmosphere produced by the terraformers.  Presumably there would be giant airlocks in the shell to let spaceships in and out.

There should be many tiny planemos in other star systems in your story which could have been terraformed by a highly advanced civilization long ago and seeded with lifeforms.

Objects smaller in mass than planemos could also have been terraformed by being given shells held up by artificial atmospheres.  Those objects wouldn't be spherical and some of them would have very unusual shapes.  But most small solar system objects in our solar system are roughly potato shaped. it should be possible to put a shell around a roughly potato shaped world and give it an artificial atmosphere.

The surface gravity could vary considerably depending on where one was on the surface, but that might not matter if the surface gravity was low enough in every part of the surface.

Deimos, a moon of Mars, has  a surface gravity of 0.003 meters per second per second, which is 0.000306 of Earth's, and an escape velocity of 5.556 meters per second, or 0.005556 kilometers per second, which is 0.0010 that of Earth.

If a world had a surface gravity 0.01 that of Earth, animals might grow 100 times as tall, or more likely might have 100 times as much mass, as Earth animals.

If a world had a surface gravity 0.001 that of Earth animals might grow 1,000 times as tall, or more likely have 1,000 times the mass, as Earth animals.

But the smaller the world, the smaller the surface area, and possibly some  worlds might have too small a surface area to support large animals like the 50 foot tall arachnids.

If you want humans from Earth to stay on your world, you have to worry about the surface gravity.  Humans have spend long periods of time on the surface of Earth with 1 *g* surface gravity, and they have spent long periods of time in the microgravity of orbiting space stations.

Humans are adapted to 1 *g* and usually don't have problems with it. Humans who spend more than about 6 months in microgravity develop health problems.
And nobody know yet where between 1 *g* and microgravity is the lower limit for the surface gravity which is long term healthy for humans.

Part Seven: A Giant Space Habitat.

And possibly the world in your story was a giant space habitat constructed by an advanced civilization long ago.

It would be a hollow cylinder, with atmosphere held inside the cylinder,
and rotating so simulated gravity would be felt on the inside of the cylinder.

And the ancient civilization which built the habitat could have made the cylinder rotate at a rate that produced a very low surface gravity inside.

If, for example, the cylinder had a radius of 1 kilometer, it would have a circumference of 6.28318 kilometers.  Each kilometer of length would have an interior surface area of 6,282.18 square kilometers, each ten kilometers of length would have an area of 62,831.8 square kilometers,
each hundred kilometers of length would have an area of 628,318 square kilometers, each thousand kilometers of length would have an area of 6,283,180 square kilometers, each ten thousand kilometers of length would have an area of 62,831,800 square kilometers, and each hundred thousand kilometers of length would have an area of 628,318,000 square kilometers, 1.231 times the surface are of Earth.

So a rotating cylindrical space habit could have arbitrarily low surface gravity combined with a surface area that could be a as large as a planet's surface.

Part Eight:  Water Arachnids.

A planet with an an Earth like surface gravity could have 50 foot tall arachnid like animals.

The giant oarfish *Regelicus glesnei*  gets very long.

> This species is the world's longest bony fish, reaching a record length of 8 m (26 ft); however, unconfirmed specimens of up to 11 m (36 ft) have been reported.[14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellworld) It is commonly measured to 3 m (9.8 ft) in total length.[15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperm_whale)

And they have been observed swimming horizontally and also swimming vertically.  One twice as long as the record specimen would be about 50 feet tall when swimming vertically.

Pods of Juvenile and adult female sperm whales *Physeter macrocephalus* have been observed sleeping vertically.

> Female sperm whales are physically mature at about 10.6 to 11 meters (35 to 36 ft) in length and generally do not achieve lengths greater than 12 metres (39 ft).[38][40][42]

So a fifty foot vertical sea creature could be about 1.42 times as tall as sleeping female sperm whales.

Males grow much larger.

> An individual measuring 20.7 metres (68 ft) was reported from a Soviet whaling fleet near the Kuril Islands in 1950 and is cited by some authors as the largest accurately measured.[38][48] It has been estimated to weigh 80 tonnes (79 long tons; 88 short tons).[47] In a review of size variation in marine megafauna, McClain and colleagues noted that the International Whaling Commission's data contained eight individuals larger than 20.7 metres (68 ft). The authors supported a 24-metre (79 ft) male from the South Pacific in 1933 as the largest recorded. However, sizes like these are rare, with 95% of recorded sperm whales below 15.85 metres (52.0 ft).[38]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperm_whale

Males may also sleep vertically, and they probably have vertical positions when returning to the surface from dives.

> The lion's mane jellyfish (Cyanea capillata), also known as the giant jellyfish, arctic red jellyfish, or the hair jelly,[2](https://www.rand.org/content/dam/rand/pubs/commercial_books/2007/RAND_CB179-1.pdf) is one of the largest known species of jellyfish.
>
> The largest recorded specimen was measured off the coast of Massachusetts in 1865 and had a bell with a diameter of 210 centimetres (7 feet) and tentacles around 36.6 m (120 ft) long.[3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giraffe)
>
> he tentacles of larger specimens may trail as long as 30 m (100 ft) or more, with the tentacles of the longest known specimen measured at 36.6 m (120 ft) in length, although it has been suggested that this specimen may actually have belonged to a different Cyanea species.[12](https://Titan%27s%20surface%20temperature%20is%20about%2094%20K%20(%E2%88%92179.2%20%C2%B0C).) This unusual length – longer than a blue whale – has earned it the status of one of the longest known animals in the world.[13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habitability_of_red_dwarf_systems)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lion%27s_mane_jellyfish

So the largest specimens, with tenticles dangling a hundred feet below the bell are more than twice as tall as fifty foot arachnids.

So if you give up on the fifty foot ancestors of your arachnid aliens living on land, they could have been fifty foot tall water arachnids living on a planet with the same surface gravity as Earth.

Comment: Wow, thank you for such a thoughtful and thorough answer, this helps quite a bit!

Comment: @Kaya Summerland  I have added a bit to part two and several other parts to my answer on May 3 to 4, offering several more suggestions.